# unable to see sdcard contents in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a database in the external storage of android phone.
I've tested databases existing with a method and it returned true.

However, I can't see the SD card contents in file explorer.

```
   public static Context context;
public static SQLiteDatabase database;
public static String SDK = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static String DB = SDK + "/database/";
```

`context = getApplicationContext();
        File file = new File(DB);
        file.mkdirs();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB + "/db.sqlite", null);`

[in this picture you can see my file explorer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X7Us.png)

[this is screenshot of ES File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooRxu.png)

Comment: You should look in SDK. What is exact path? /storage/emulated/0 ?

Comment: @greenapps Yes the SDK is  = /storage/emulated/0
but emulated folder is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem solved . I Found a way to see sdcard files and get a copy of "db.sqlite"

i opened adb shell and used this command to copy my database file:
 `adb pull /sdcard/database/db.sqlite`
 and a copy of this file created in `C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools` folder

and used this command to see my sdcard directory and files :`adb shell ls /sdcard/`